# Golang beginner, on Windows: System cannot find file specified

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Only just now starting with golang, with only a small amount of programming experience before this. I'm trying to create a script that will summarize certain things from a csv file, but I haven't even gotten past testing out file reading yet.

I was having trouble reading the excel files, and kept getting the "System cannot find file specified" error. So I thought I'd see if I could at least get it to read a simple text file, using an example from golangbot, which looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("File reading error", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Contents of file:", string(data))
}
```

That simple. The text file is located within the same folder (in %USERPROFILE%/go/src, and /go/ is my GOPATH) as the actual code file I'm attempting to run, and yes, it is called "test.txt". Yet, every attempt to run gives me the same error message, that the system cannot find the specified file (test.txt).

Running any other kind of .go file or building one from this location works just fine. I'm seen others with this error, but it seemed like it was always to do with the GOPATH being set wrong.

I'm frustrated that I even have to ask about something like this, but it's all I could think of right now. Is there something wrong with the locations of my files or the GOPATH itself, or is this something different?

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't have any files in the root of `$GOPATH/src`. The relative location of the file in relation to your program source doesn't matter. Are you certain that `test.txt` is in the current working directory where you execute your program?

Comment: Yep, I’m sure. It’s right there under the .go file. I plopped the files into the src root because other workspace locations didn’t work either. Most bizarre.

Comment: Other workspace location _will_ work, you might want to carefully read through the  basic documentation in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). As I mentioned, the path relative to the `.go` files is irrelevant, it needs to be relative to your working directory.

Comment: Go version: go version go1.10.2 windows/amd64. 
Go Path is: GOPATH=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\go. 

The Golang.org output does indeed say no such file or directory.

As for the location of the workspace and the files: %GOPATH%/src/github.com/GolangCode. This is the location of the code as well as the txt file. Is this incorrect?

I've read the Go Playground guide earlier today, but it seems I must have misunderstood something.

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter where `test.txt` is relative to the *code*. When you run this program, it will look for `test.txt` in the *current working directory* where you run it.

Comment: Okay, embarrassing question: by _current working directory_ do you mean the directory of the program that is being run? Because everything specifically related to this code is in the same directory, the one I outlined above.

Comment: yes ... I don't have a windows machine handy however right click on file test.txt and look maybe under properties for its full path possibly  "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\go\src\test.txt"    then in your code use this full path instead of simply "text.txt"

Comment: I’ll give that a shot, thanks

Comment: "C:\Users\yourusername\go\src\test.txt"   or possibly "C:/Users/yourusername/go/src/test.txt"    ... just avoid embedding %USERNAME%  as that will not get resolved

Comment: UPDATE: Absolute path also doesn't work. Still no solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welp, the problem was solved. Turns out, the actual name of the txt file was test.txt.txt. Thanks to notepad and my own lack of awareness.

Bit embarrassing, really. Changing the name worked.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. I forgot that OS hides file name extensions by default =)

Comment: I would recommend everyone using Windows change the setting to hide known file extensions. Many ways to achieve this, easy one is `In Explorer window, View > Options > View tab > Advanced Settings` and Uncheck the `Hide extensions for known file types` option.

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying this with your notepad. Be cautious while saving it.

The file type should be compatible

- File -> save as >
  FileName : FileName.go
  Save as type : All Files
- Now execute as ("folder path">go run FileName.go

Then the result. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar issue as well. I would try to do this in order to fix it. delete the file and create a new one. That is a simple solution in my opinion. Make sure to copy the code and then paste onto the new file. Mkdir
cd into that directory touch or nano
create a new file. then open that file. then do go run that file name.
it should work.